# Problems with fixed nav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav, fixed

I have problems with fixed nav, its showing little more down on section links. I need nav on the top to see clearly the title text at the sections. I have tried to add margin-top to section, but these gaps are so big and its awful so I need another solution for that.
Pictures are there:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T99W.png)

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhTRO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed elements are not included in the Normal Flow.

In order to fix this, you'd need to make the underlying element larger by applying a `padding-top` with the same height as the fixed nav.

Answer (score 0):

**You can to add a margin-top but its not good practice n just try to drag the element Lorem Ipsuim into the section that have the background Blue.**
-then select the element in that relied the navbar (Home , About ,etc) inside a div and add them the background color green .

(check if the lorem ipsuim text have a position static not absolute)